# how to make it always be a drop of stone?

Tags: java, bukkit

I do not know how to do so that there is always a stone item that has a certain chance, eg there is a pool of items, in total it is 100%. Just when a player destroys stone, he always falls out with something from the pot.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please ([edit] your attempts into this question - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you are trying to say,

You want a stone block to drop different items randomly.

To do that you will have to make an event listener class, and listen for the BlockBreakEvent.

Next, check if the block type equals the stone material.

Then make all of the possible item drops and their probability into a map. Ex. 5 Stone, 4 Iron, 1 Diamond.

Use the random class to generate a number with the max being the sum of all the probabilities and the min being 0. Then iterate through the probabilities, and get the one that is the highest probability below the random number.

Then spawn in that ItemStack and cancel the event so Cobblestone won't spawn.